# sendRedirect don't work after AsyncContext

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I have a dynamic web app (java and tomcat 7)
In a servlet

```
AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync(request,response);
Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
asyncContext.start(new BackgroundTask(newFile, user.getEmail(), configDoc, con, user.getId()));
response.sendRedirect("/fit/home");
```

But `sendRedirect` don't work?
How can I fix it?

Comment: What does _don't work_ mean?

Comment: I want to go to 'fit/home', but it doesn't go

Comment: @storky, did you encountered 404 error ?

Comment: No, It just stay in /upload

Comment: Are you sending ajax request?